# Escape %d for pdfseparate in a thunar custom action

Tags: bash, pdf, thunar

I want to create a thunar custom action that lets me right-click a PDF and then select "split PDF" to split it into individual pages.  The command to do this is:

```
$ pdfseparate mypdf.pdf mypdf-%d.pdf
```

Which will create a new PDF for each page, called `mypdf-1.pdf`, `mypdf-2.pdf`, etc. `%d` is replaced by the pdfseparate command with a page number as per the man page:

> ```
> SYNOPSIS
>     pdfseparate [options] PDF-file PDF-page-pattern
> ```

> ```
> PDF-page-pattern should contain %d (or any variant respecting printf format), since %d is replaced by the page number.
> ```

[Thunar custom actions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ThunarCustomActions) interpolate any `%n` as the selected file any `%d` with the directory the file is in.  So if I try to replicate the above command, replacing `mypdf.pdf` with `%n`, it looks like this:

```
pdfseparate "%n" "$(basename "%n" .pdf)-%d.pdf"
```

However, then thunar will replace the `%d` with the file's directory.  How can I escape the `%d` so it will be passed on to `pdfseparate` verbatim?

`pdfseparate` does not appear to have an option to use a different variable than `%d` but it does say it accepts "any variant respecting printf format".  I'm not sure what that means... I tried `%s` and it didn't work.

Comment: In printf-like tools, you can often use `%%` for a literal `%`, so try something like `pdfseparate "%n" "$(basename "%n" .pdf)-%%d.pdf"`, that might escape the `%` in `%d` and pass it as is to pdfseparate. Does that work?

Comment: @terdon Yes, post it as an answer for credit.  The `"%n"`s must be unquoted though or the quotes are interpreted as part of the filename.  Thunar must be interpreting the `%n` literally because I tested it unquoted on files with spaces in the name and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In printf-like tools, you can often use `%%` for a literal `%`. For example, in the man page of the `printf` found in the standard C library (see `man 3 printf`), you will see:

```
       %      A '%' is written.  No argument is converted.  The complete conversion specification is '%%'.
```

So, to escape the `%` and have it treated as a literal `%`, just use `%%`. In your case, that means the command you want to give to thunar is:

```
pdfseparate %n "$(basename %n .pdf)-%%d.pdf"
```

Comment: Good, however, when I tested with the `\"`s, the output files got quotes in the filenames as in `"myfile"-1.pdf`.

Comment: @ki9 hmm. The thing is without the quotes, it will almost certainly break if you try it on a file whose name contains spaces. I don't know exactly how it should be quoted without trying, but some quoting in the `basename` command will be needed. I'll remove them now, but if you try with a file named something like `foo bar.pdf`, let me know how it goes!

Comment: I did test it on a file with spaces and it does work as you have it now, creating files like `foo bar-1.pdf`.  Like I said, I guess thunar is already treating %n like a single parameter as if it were already "%n".

Comment: @ki9 OK, great. You must be right and it is passing the `%n` quoted. I thought the `%n` was used and expanded by pdfseparate but if it isn't, then great!